# Python, Rock, Paper, Scissor

Tags: python, rock-paper-scissors

Recently i wanted to test my Python knowledge so I'm taking some challenges. I came across a Rock Paper Scissor challenge and I wanted to make it with less code and reuse the same code over and over. The code below is what I have written so far and it works great. I just want to get your opinions: what can i do better?

```
rules = {
    'rock': {
        'scissor': 'smashes'
    },
    'paper': {
        'rock': 'packs'
    },
    'scissor': {
        'paper': 'cuts'
    }
}

player_one = input("P1 | Rock, Paper or Scissor: ").lower()
player_two = input("P2 | Rock, Paper or Scissor: ").lower()


def play(p1, p2):
    if p1 in rules:
        if p2 in rules[p1]:
            print("{} {} {}".format(p1, rules[p1][p2], p2))

    if p2 in rules:
        if p1 in rules[p2]:
            print("{} {} {}".format(p2, rules[p2][p1], p1))

    if p1 not in rules or p2 not in rules:
        print("Invalid input")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    play(player_one, player_two)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the validation first, to eliminate redundant conditionals.

```
def play(p1, p2):
    if p1 not in rules or p2 not in rules:
        print("Invalid input")
    elif p2 in rules[p1]:
        print("{} {} {}".format(p1, rules[p1][p2], p2))
    elif p1 in rules[p2]:
        print("{} {} {}".format(p2, rules[p2][p1], p1))
```

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right. This is what i was looking for, a nice upgrade to my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't let your users give bad input. You could use a TUI framework such as Inquirer to guide your users to chose from a list.

Also you should avoid to put business code at the top level scope of your module. You should define `player_one` and `player_two` from a method. Code that is at the top level scope of your module is only ever executed once as it's not reexecuted when you import after the first import.